Trouble Running .NET 8 Projects After Installing SDK 8
I recently installed .NET SDK 8 and verified its installation using the command dotnet --version, which shows 8.0.204. However, when I attempt to open a project targeting .NET 8, I encounter the following error:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NETSDK1045  The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 8.0.  Either target .NET 7.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 8.0.    ConsoleApp5 C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.203\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets   144
This is puzzling because my installed SDK appears to be up-to-date. Here's the output of dotnet --list-sdks:
5.0.409 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
7.0.203 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
8.0.204 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
and the version:
C:\Users\user1>
and when i run:
dotnet --version
8.0.204
As you can see, SDK 8.0.204 is indeed installed.
Can anyone help me diagnose and solve this issue? I'm at a loss for what could be causing it. Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide.
I've tried verifying the installation of the .NET SDK by running dotnet --version, which confirmed that SDK 8.0.204 is installed. Additionally, I've checked the list of installed SDKs using dotnet --list-sdks, which also confirms the presence of SDK 8.0.204. Despite this, I still encounter the error mentioned previously when attempting to open a project targeting .NET 8. I expected that with the correct SDK installed, the project would compile and run without any issues on .NET 8. However, the error persists, and I dont understand.

Is there a file called global.json anywhere in your project?

It seems that your msbuild does not pick the right sdk.Can you try go to your project folder and use dotnet build <your_project_file> and see if it can build your .NET 8 project.You can also reference to
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/sdk-errors/netsdk1045
to check potential cause of your issue.

I don't have a global json file inside the project itself
But when I open the bin folder
I see two folders one named net7 which has some files in it
and one named net8 which is empty
If I do a build on the project it still doesn't let net8.0 run like that
Only if I change to net7.0 do I succeed
But I want to advance to 8...

If you want to use .NET8 keep using it, but in global.json file keep the version 9.0.0 this is the SDK version.
Things will work fine this way.

I managed to solve the problem
I went to "Add or Remove Programs" on the computer.
I had both SDK 7 and SDK 8 installed there
I removed by visual studio installer (modify) the version of 7
I updated the version of vs 2022
And works great
Thanks to all the helpers
